# Edit file in QT

Tags: qt, file, text-files

I am trying to edit .txt file in QT. I am writing data in test.txt file whenever I write new data it remove the previous data. What I am looking for is as following:

Check either the file exist or not.
If yes update the file by inserting the new data in file with timestamp
If no than create new file and insert data.

```
void writefile(QString Filename)
{
    QFile mFile(Filename);

     if(!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Not open file";
        return;
    }

    // we can use stream instead of OUT FOR OUTPUT
     QTextStream out(&mFile);
    out << PCAN_DEVICE_NUMBER << ", " << PCAN_HARDWARE_NAME ;

   // mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
```

Comment: and your programming problem is...?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the file open command attributes to `(QFile::Append|QFile::Text)`, 
because the `QFile::WriteOnly` implies the `QFile::Truncate`.

```
mFile.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text)
```

You can have a look into the documentation for `QIODevice`:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum

Answer (score 0):

Use the append flag for opening your file

```
!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QIODevice::Append)
```